# Are item passives implicitly passed on into higher tier items?

Tags: league-of-legends

When upgrading an item with a passive effect into another item, is this passive still included in the upgraded item, even when not specified? It seems counter-intuitive that it would not, but I am still unsure.

For example, Seeker's Armguard has a passive which grants 0.5 armour and ability power upon killing a unit, stacking up to 30 times. Seeker's Armguard then builds into Zhonya's Hourglass, which does not list the same passive effect (it only has a unique active: stasis). Am I to assume it does in fact include the Seeker's Armguard passive effect and it is just hidden, or that it does not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case of Zhonya's Hourglass, the item itself incorporates the passive in form of its +45 to armor which is +5 armor in comparison to the armguard itself.

However, if not explicitly stated otherwise on the item itself, no passives are transferred between upgrades of items.

Answer (score 2):

It is not the case that passives automatically get carried over.  If an upgrade does not list the passive, then it is lost.  A great example of this is going from [Catalyst the Protector](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Catalyst_the_Protector), which has the passive "Valor's Reward", while [Righteous Glory](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Righteous_Glory), which builds out of Catalyst the Protector, does not have the passive Valor's Reward. Owning a Righteous Glory will not give you the health/mana regeneration upon leveling up.